# Re-route all audio from tablet to PC-Speakers

Tags: audio, speaker

My setup is the following: I have a PC and a tablet (Nexus 7), and only one sound system (2.1, 3.5mm input). My goal is to play both sounds coming from my PC and from my Nexus 7 whilst it is in the (official) docking station through the speaker-system hooked up to my PC.

I've looked for a way to merge the two incoming signals but without any success (except for cost-heavy DJ equipment to mix both signals), so now I'm wondering if it's possible to simply re-route all outgoind audio via USB to my PC (both running Windows and Linux (Ubuntu)).

I'd appreciate any help you guys can give me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5890711/shoe-racks-headphone-splitters-and-more-screw-tricks/), you can use a headphone splitter in reverse to achieve your goal.